# Logging into Mongo on Amazon's EC2 (AWS) with MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongodb-.net-driver

This question is specific to MongoVUE, but really I am looking to be able to log in to Mongo on EC2 in any way besides through the SSH tunnel. I can do that and get a server and client up and running, create documents, find things etc. I am new to mongo and ec2 so I will admit there are a lot of variables.

Here is what I've done so far:

I have created a unique database and then added a user to that with the db.addUser('name','password') command.

I am using the public dns that AWS provided which looks like, xxxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I have tried to log in with the plain text password as well as the one mongo displays (hashed).

My ultimate goal is to be able to connect through C#, but MongoVue gives me an easier platform to fiddle around with (I hope).

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Try to get things working without a MongoDB user -- I tried to use one once, but it was more trouble than it's worth. Once you get everything humming, then you can decide whether to use a user/password or not. Also, it sounds like you might be trying to log in to an SSH tunnel using a Mongo username/password -- if this is the case, you'll need to use the SSH username and password instead to establish the connection (and then, on top of that, the Mongo credentials to log in to MongoDB).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing and it actually ended up being pretty easy after following the instructions on Mongovue's Blog

http://www.mongovue.com/2011/08/04/mongovue-connection-to-remote-server-over-ssh/

This allows you to not have to open up the MongoDB port externally also.

Make sure you also convert your EC2 .pem key to a Putty Key via PuttyGen first.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it for those of you that will find this question and be in the same boat. For some reason I could not change my security group on ec2 to the one I had given access to port 27017. So I added that port exception to the security group that was currently assigned to my instance.

I then had to log in through SSH to get the Mongo server up and running (simply run the mongod command in the bin directory) and then it logged right in. I used the username and password that I had set up earlier through the mongo command line.

I hope this helps someone.